# ¿Como puedo pasar parametro de una vista a otra mediante Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails

Estoy intentando pasar por parámetro un `id` que obtengo y el cual es el identificador que estaré usando posteriormente para consultar la información relacionada, mi problema radica en lo siguiente, al hacer el llamado de la función externa:

```
$('.modalDetail').click(function () {
  var templateId = $(this).closest(".templateInfo").first().attr("id").split("template-id-")[1];
  console.log("El dato de templateId: " + templateId);
  dataOfTemplate(templateId);

  data-dismiss="modal"
  $('#modalSheetDetail').modal("show");
})
```

En donde **`dataOfTemplate(templateId);`** es la función externa a la cual quiero mandar el id por parámetro.

```
/**obtener datos para llenar la vista de detalle**/
 function dataOfTemplate(templateId){
```

Como dato extra, estoy trabajando con `Grails` y el render de la página la tengo dentro del archivo en donde intento enviar el parámetro.

**Error que se presenta cuando pongo un log he intento recuperar el parámetro en la otra vista**

```
ReferenceError: dataOfTemplate is not defined
index:2489:21
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entra a la función para obtener datos del template: **`undefined`**

**ACTUALIZACION**

Acabo de quitar el `$(document).ready(function(){}` el archivo en donde quiero recibir el parámetro y al parecer con eso se resolvió el problema pero ahora me envía dos veces el paramero, la primera con impresión si tiene el parámetro pero la segunda me manda un **`undefined`**

Entra a la funcion para obtener datos del template: **1**
Entra a la funcion para obtener datos del template: **`undefined`**

fragmento del código en donde pongo el log para verificar que recibo el parámetro con un dato.

```
function dataOfTemplate(templateId){
            console.log("Entra a la funcion para obtener datos del template: "+templateId);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y cuál es el problema? qué error te manda?

Comment: Que tal Vick agradezco tu ayuda, acabo de editar mi pregunta

Comment: Estas agregando un `$(document).ready(function(){
/*aqui todo tu código*/
})` ?

Comment: Si, en los dos archivos tengo primero $(document).ready(function(){}